# Getting Current Address using GPS

Tags: android, gps

I want to get Current Address Using GPS provider .I am getting lat lng values with zero  while i use GPS.I want current location without using Wifi.And I got exception when i convert to alt lng values to address using GeoCoder ("unable to parse response from server")I am unable to do this please Help me

My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnClickListener{

LocationManager locationManager ;
String provider;
Button btn;
private String strAdd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10, 30, this);

        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tvAdd  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    //TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Log.e("LATLNG", ""+lat+lng);
   Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    try{
         List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);
          if (addresses != null) {
              Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
              StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

              for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                  strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
              }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();

          }
    }
          catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
    tvLongitude.setText("LAT LNG:" + lat+lng);

    tvAdd.setText("ADDRESS:" + strAdd);

    // Setting Current Latitude
   // tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Where are you testing your code ? in emulator or in real device ?

Comment: testing on real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a 0 value in lat long I think you're unable to receive a GPS response. GPS might take lot of time to get its first fix sometimes upto 15 minutes depending on the visibility of satellites. So, when you're only using GPS make sure you're in an outdoor location to get a faster fix.

Also, you'll need to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` since Geocoder will need to send the lat lng to online servers to get the address.

Comment: can i get address without using internet?

Comment: You might if you have the whole database of lat long to address conversion in your android device. but that is impossible.

Comment: @ShivamVerma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408421/facebook-retrieving-whole-friendlist-in-android-application-is-impossible please help me with this if you can.

Comment: @nobalG Sorry, what are you trying to say ?

Comment: @Durga Please accept the answer if it works for you :-)

Comment: the above link which i posted in comments, is the problem currently i am facing.I want your help if you can as none of the others have replied for my query.

Comment: @Shivam Verma is my above code current for getting lat lng values using gps?

Comment: If you don't get the toast saying no providers found, then yes :-)

Comment: I am getting toast Location can't be retrieved

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG:**

it will simply call `onLocationChanged(location)` even when last known location contains (0,0) as lat-long.

```
    if(location!=null)
        onLocationChanged(location);
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**CORRECT:**

add validation on it as mentioned below so `onLocationChanged(location)` will be called only when `either it has valid location or when it will receive new location using LocationManager`.

```
    if(location!=null){
        if(location.location.getLatitude()>0 || location.getLongitude()>0) 
        {
           onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```